# SSIS SQL Task will not return results from XML column

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package with a variable of data type String.

I have a table with an XML field and I am trying to get data from this field and populate my variable. I have tried numerous ways:

1.-

```
SELECT ISNULL(STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + wrk.CustomFieldsXML.value('(/values/MatterUNO)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS [text()]
    FROM Work wrk
    WHERE ISNULL(wrk.CustomFieldsXml.value('(values/ReleaseSecureMattertoFoundation)[1]', 'varchar(5)'), 'false') = 'true'
    FOR XML path('')), 1, 1, ''), '') AS 'RESULT'
```

2.-

```
DECLARE @RESULT VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @RESULT = ISNULL(STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + wrk.CustomFieldsXML.value('(/values/MatterUNO)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS [text()]
    FROM Work wrk
    WHERE ISNULL(wrk.CustomFieldsXml.value('(values/ReleaseSecureMattertoFoundation)[1]', 'varchar(5)'), 'false') = 'true'
    FOR XML path('')), 1, 1, ''), '')

SELECT ISNULL(@RESULT, '') AS 'RESULT'
```

3.-

```
SELECT wrk.CustomFieldsXML.value('(/values/MatterUNO)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'RESULT'
FROM Work wrk
WHERE ISNULL(wrk.CustomFieldsXml.value('(values/ReleaseSecureMattertoFoundation)[1]', 'varchar(5)'), 'false') = 'true'
```

4.-

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(wrk.CustomFieldsXML.value('(/values/MatterUNO)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), '')
FROM Work wrk
WHERE ISNULL(wrk.CustomFieldsXml.value('(values/ReleaseSecureMattertoFoundation)[1]', 'varchar(5)'), 'false') = 'true')  AS 'RESULT'
```

Each of these results in 2 errors:

1. The value type (_ComObject) can only be converted to variables with type Object.
2. The type of the value (DBNull) being assigned to variable differs from current type (String).

When I change the SQL to be: **SELECT '988776' AS 'RESULT'** the variable assignment works fine.

Does anyone know whether this is a limitation with working with XML columns?
Can anyone help?

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value of type `Varchar(MAX)` from **SQL Task** cannot be assigned to SSIS variable directly. This accounts for the error

> The value type (_ComObject) can only be converted to variables with type Object.

Ways to fix it:

1. Return a more bounded data type, i.e. `Varchar(8000)` (no more than 8000) or `NVarchar(4000)` (no more than 4000), taking the risk of data truncation. This valus can be assigned by **SQL Task** to your string variable.
2. Return a `Varchar(MAX)` value and assign it to an Object type variable. Besides, you have to return `Full Result set` in properties of SQL Task. Then, in the next step - set a **Foreach Loop** enumerator, and store **0-th** column into your string variable in Variables mappings. Here is a [good walkthrough](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14341/Using-the-Foreach-ADO-Enumerator-in-SSIS) on how to do this.

The second option seems a little bit strange, but it works.

Comment: Thanks Ferdipux. The varchar(8000) has solved the issue. I would never have found that. Very much appreciated.